# caption overlapped on plot label

Tags: floats, input, gnuplot, epslatex

I have a plot obtained with gnuplot with epslatex terminal. So, I have two output files from gnuplot: foo.eps with the graph and foo.tex with the label also. To include the plot in my latex document I have write

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{toptesi}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\input{foo}
\caption{bla bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the caption apparently see only the .eps and write over the labels contained in the .tex file. How to tell the caption to write at the bottom of the entire plot (image+labels)?

The problem is with all gnuplot+epslatex graphs. I do something like

```
set term epslatex
set output 'foo.tex'
set xlabel '$x$'
set ylabel '$f\left(x\right)$'
plot 'data.dat' u 1:2 w lines
```

and the caption is always under the image but overlapped with the x-label. There is a way to move the caption manually even if is not the elegant way?

Comment: Why don't you use `\includegraphics` for the eps-file?

Comment: Because the .eps file doesn't have the labels... This is why gnuplot in epslatex mode gives you two output files: one for the plot and one for the latex labels.

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't know this, thanks.

Comment: Can you make the files generated by gnuplot available for download? Alternatively, you could edit your question and add a gnuplot script which creates files that reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited but, as I have explain, you can use any gnuplot+epslatex graph and the problem is there (for me at least)...

Comment: I can't reproduce this: The caption doesn't overlap the axis label for me. What compiler are you using (`latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`)? What version of `gnuplot` are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: This is interesting :-) I use pdflatex and the latest version of gnuplot...

Comment: What happens if you use `latex+dvips`?

Comment: Thank a lot! It seem to work with latex+dvips+ps2pdf! But in my document I have a lot of \includegraphics with jpg images that dvi doesn't support... How to do that?

Comment: When `pdflatex` encounters an `eps` image it converts it to `pdf`; it appears that the problem originates at this step of the process. The converted files have names such as 'fig-eps-converted-to.pdf'. What happens if you remove these and do the conversions yourself using `epstopdf`?

Comment: The problem is that the eps doesn't have the labels that are in the tex. So with an \includegraphics{foo.eps} I couldn't have any labels... That is exactly the problem. Using \input{foo.tex} I have all because in the tex file there is a figure and the labels... But here comes the problem with caption....

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you use `\includegraphics` directly. Just convert the `eps` files produced by `gnuplot` to `pdf` using `eps2pdf` so that `pdflatex` doesn't need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When the `epslatex` terminal is used, gnuplot produces an `eps` file and a separate file containing `tex` code. This `tex` code includes the image using `\includegraphics`, and adds labels etc. using the picture environment. If this code is used in a document that is compiled by `pdflatex`, the `eps` file will be converted to `pdf` before inclusion. If gnuplot creates `plot.tex` and `plot.eps`, then, after compilation there will also be a file called `plot-eps-converted-to.pdf`.

Now it's difficult to determine exactly what is happening because I can't reproduce the problem on my machine. However, from the fact that the problem does not occur with `latex+dvips`, we can deduce that the automatic `eps` to `pdf` conversion is not working properly. It's probably worth opening some of the `-eps-converted-to.pdf` files in a viewer to see if the problem is visible. As a workaround, I suggest removing the `-eps-converted-to.pdf` files and doing the conversions yourself using `eps2pdf` so that `pdflatex` doesn't have to do it.

Comment: No, the manual conversion of the eps file doesn't work. I can't try the latex+dvips+ps2pdf with my document because of the jpg \includegraphics. I don't think the problem is the conversion, because it goes all right with both methods. And the real problem is not with the images that are nice but with the caption!

Comment: @bluePhlavio --- the most likely cause of an image overlapping a caption is a problem with the image itself, but since I can't reproduce the issue my efforts so far have been guesswork. I suggest you compose a short, complete example consisting of the `tex` file(s), `gnuplot script`, data file(s) (if needed), the files generated by `gnuplot` and the `-eps-converted-to.pdf'` file, and add this to your question. Images can be uploaded to remote hosting sites and linked from here.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The problem arises only with multiplot mode and with zero bmargin... The reformulated problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518490/caption-on-gnuplot-multiplot-mode